# Calling an overridden function from a base constructor

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, derived-class

It makes sense that I should not call an overridden function from a base constructor, since the derived class is not yet constructed.

But I want to use this design pattern, where each derived class provides methods for calculating the properties of the base class since the properties should be immutable and assigned at the constructor.

#### Shape.cs

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    protected Shape()
    {
        Area = 0f;
        Center = Vector2.Zero;
        const int n = 36;
        float du = 1/(float)n, dv = 1/(float)n;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            float u = (i+0.5f)*du;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                float v = (i+0.5f)*dv;
                float f = GetAreaElement(u, v);
                // Warning: Remove this call from a constructor to the overridable 'GetAreaElement' method.
                Area += f*du*dv;
                Center += GetPosition(u, v)*f*du*dv;
                // Warning: Remove this call from a constructor to the overridable 'GetPosition' method.
            }
        }
        Center /= Area;
    }

    public abstract Vector2 GetPosition(float u, float v);
    protected abstract float GetAreaElement(float u, float v);

    public float Area { get;  }
    public Vector2 Center { get; }
}

public class Circle : Shape
{
    public Circle(float radius)
    {
        Radius=radius;
    }

    public float Radius { get; }

    public override Vector2 GetPosition(float u, float v)
    {
        float r = u*Radius, θ = (float)(2*Math.PI)*v;
        return new Vector2(
            r*(float)Math.Cos(θ),
            r*(float)Math.Sin(θ));
    }

    protected override float GetAreaElement(float u, float v)
    {
        return u*Radius;
    }
}

public class Rectangle : Shape
{
    public Rectangle(float side1, float side2)
    {
        Side1=side1;
        Side2=side2;
    }

    public float Side1 { get; }
    public float Side2 { get; }

    public override Vector2 GetPosition(float u, float v)
    {
        return new Vector2((u-0.5f)*Side1, (v-0.5f)*Side2);
    }

    protected override float GetAreaElement(float u, float v)
    {
        return Side1*Side2;
    }
}
```

So what is the solution here? I want to use the base constructor to define the properties, and the calculation depends on the implementation of the derived class.

#### Workaround 1 - Future calculator

A workaround would be to provide a `protected` function that calculates the properties, each to be called from each constructor of the derived class, but there is **no enforcement** here. If one class forgets to call the calculator function the whole thing falls apart. And the properties are now `private set` which is **not immutable** really.

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    protected void Calculate()
    {
        ...
        float f = GetAreaElement(u, v);
        ...
        Center += GetPosition(u, v)*f*du*dv;
        ...
    }

    public abstract Vector2 GetPosition(float u, float v);
    protected abstract float GetAreaElement(float u, float v);

    public float Area { get; private set; }
    public Vector2 Center { get; private set; }
}

public class Circle : Shape
{
    public Circle(float radius)
    {
        Radius=radius;

        base.Calculate();
    }

    public float Radius { get; }

    public override Vector2 GetPosition(float u, float v)
    {
        ...
    }

    protected override float GetAreaElement(float u, float v)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

#### Workaround 2 - Function delegates

Another workaround would be to supply the delegates to the required function implementations as arguments to the base class constructor.

```
public delegate float AreaFactor(float u, float v);
public delegate Vector2 PositionFunc(float u, float v);
public abstract class Shape
{
    protected Shape(AreaFactor a, PositionFunc p)
    {
        this.GetAreaElement = a;
        this.GetPosition = p;
        ...
        float f = a(u, v);
        this.Center += p(u, v)*f*du*dv;
        ...
    }

    public float Area { get; }
    public Vector2 Center { get;  }

    public AreaFactor GetAreaElement { get; }
    public PositionFunc GetPosition { get; }
}

public class Circle : Shape
{
    public Circle(float radius)
        : base(
              (u, v) => u*radius, 
              (u,v)=>
                {
                    float r = u*radius, θ = (float)(2*Math.PI)*v;
                    return new Vector2(
                        r*(float)Math.Cos(θ),
                        r*(float)Math.Sin(θ));
                })
    {
        Radius=radius;
    }

    public float Radius { get; }
}
```

This seems a bit clunky to me, and I am not sure I like the function delegate properties, instead of overridden methods.

#### Question/Challege

Can [SO] provide some other ways of achieving the above-stated goals

- Base properties are immutable
- Base properties are calculated at the constructor based on the implementation details of the derived classes.
- Each derived class holds its own immutable properties used to describe the derived class.

Comment: What about a `Lazy<T>`?

Comment: @Llama - so a lazy backing field, with the property pointing to the resulting value. That is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preference is to go with Option 2 - passing to the base constructor the methods to generate the derived properties. It does satisfy all your requirements. If aesthetics is a concern, perhaps using a `Func` might make the code easier to read. The key is that the `Func`'s are static methods, which should not be a problem since they calculate immutable properties of the object.

```
void Main()
{
    var square = new Square(5);
}

public abstract class Shape
{
    protected Shape(Func<int> areaFunc)
    {
        Area = areaFunc();
    }

    public int Area { get; }
}

public class Square : Shape
{
    public Square(int side): base( () =>  CalcArea(side) )
    {
        Side = side;
    }
    
    static int CalcArea(int side) => side * side;

    public int Side { get; }
}
```

Comment: The main issue here is that the calculation method is identical for all derived types but only varies which two functions it uses for `GetAreaElement()` and `GetPosition()`. So repeating the same code over and over again is not ideal for maintainability.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to, instead of calculating the `Area` and `Center` in the constructor, lazily calculate them in the property getter. It will require a backing field to know if the property has been calculated or not, but it will get rid of the warning.

It also seems odd to me that you don't *pass* the center to the `Shape` constructor, but I don't fully understand the design you're using.

Comment: Ideally, I would do my calculations in the derived class constructor, and pass the results to the base constructor for assignment. But because C# calls base constructor _before_ the derived constructor I need to use delegates (or `Func<T>`). This eliminates the option to use overridden methods and forces me to choose between static methods (not inherited) or internal functions. 

There has to be a cleaner way to do this. I only hope.

Comment: Why would you do that calculation in the constructor? It's not _needed_ for construction - it's only needed when you want to get one of the calculated properties. So I see nothing wrong with doing that calculation at property-get time (only caching the result for performance reasons)

Comment: The calculation is expensive and it needs to be done one time in order to assign the values to the properties. There are two abstract functions that are used for the calculation and the result of the calculation here is two values, but it could be more in the future.

Comment: Okay, but I still don't see why you can't do it lazily in the property getter, but it looks like you're found a workaround.

Comment: The `Lazy<>()` pipework requires a parameterless `Func<T>` and supplies one value. To make it work  I would need to imitate Option 2 and return a tuple containing all the property values to be set. That is more complex than just supplying the delegates as in Option 2 and doing to calculation on the constructor.

Comment: You don't necessarily need `Lazy<T>`. Just a nullable backing field that you check when you get the property - and calculate it if it isn't set. Again, you've found something that works for you - just offering my opinion...